# How to import spdlog into a CMake project?

Tags: cmake, spdlog, external-project, fetchcontent

I'm desperately trying to understand how cmake works. I inherited a project that uses cmake, and needs spdlog, but I simply cannot make cmake be able to generate the makefiles, because I cannot produce a working Findspdlog.cmake for find_package to work.

Is there a way to use spdlog properly with FetchContent, or am I forced to install it?

I found a Findspdlog.cmake that relies on ExternalProject, but that's not good, because than you cannot use the targets from the project, until you already have done a build, which you cannot do, because makefile generation fails. I'm going in circles for hours.